# in node.js / socket.io, how to tell if an object is an instanceof a socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

in my app the `socket` is passed around as `this` using `bind` and `call`

```
socket.on( 'handle', someFunc.bind(socket) );

function someFunc() {
  var socket = this;
  ...
  anotherFunc.call( socket, 'abc', ... );
}
```

I wish to ensure that `this` is indeed a `socket` - forgetting - using `func(...)` instead of `func.call(socket,...)`.

```
function someFunc() {
  var socket = this;
  assert.ok( /* ensure this is instanceof a socket */ );
  ...
}
```

how do I make the assertion?

is there some `socket` within `io = require('socket.io')` that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the specific problem in question, it is probably better to check whether `this` is not null:

```
function someFunc() {
  var socket = this;
  assert.ok(socket);
  ...
}
```

The assert will fail for `someFunc();` call, and will only pass for `someFunc.bind(socket)();` and `someFunc.call(socket);` calls (as long as `socket` is not null).

Relying on the implementation details, as Bergi suggested, will render your application unusable should the next Node.js version feature a different implementation; and it does not seem to be a part of the public API.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in [the source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/socket.io.js#L77), it returns a [`Manager`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/manager.js) instance. This check should work:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var socket = io.listen(...);

socket instanceof io.Manager; // true
```

Comment: do not think so.  `assert.ok( socket instanceof server.io.Manager )` => TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got #<Socket>

Comment: Isn't `Manager` a constructor function? Could you please log it?

Comment: sorry taking so long getting back.  it appears that `Manager` disappears after being instantiated - look using `util.inspect`.